# Smiley character support in browser?

Tags: unicode, browser

when I search for a smiley character in Internet Explorer, it support that character and displays as is given [Smiley in Internet Explorer](http://postimg.org/image/ewa5t392h/) but it does not support it in chrome  [Smiley in chrome](http://postimg.org/image/qnrlw9gq1/). I want to show a smiley in my website, but the smiley gets displayed in Internet Explorer but not in chrome, how to fix this issue?

Comment: As a question about using browsers and Google, this appears to be off-topic at SO. Interpreted as a question about HTML and CSS coding, it lacks sufficient information; you should identify which character you mean and how you are trying to use (i.e., show HTML and CSS code).

Comment: The provided links explain what @user3532803 want to explain on their question